# Tomcat 404 page for other context request

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have an applciation deployed at the Context `sam1` My URL will be like 
`http://localhost:2/sam1/bla` when I try to access `http://localhost:2/sam1/bla1` which resource is not exist then I have my custom 404 error page handle in the `sam1` application as

`web.xml`

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/notfound.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

This is working.

But when I try to access `http://localhost:2/sam1222/bla` I don't have control on this. For this, I found from SO that we need to enable the same thing in Tomcat web.xml file. I've done this in my eclipse project `Servers` the same xml tags I have given. After this I tried to access the `http://localhost:2/sam1222/bla` I got broken page exception.

What am I missing?

Correct me, if my understanding is wrong. Pardon me, if this is duplicate.

**UPDATE**
I'm using Tomcat 7.0.64

Comment: I think your war name is sam1.war then why you are trying to access it via sam1222

Comment: Mainsh is right.. its like Negative testcase

Comment: @MainshPrajapati I need to provide custom 404 error page for friendly response. In any public website you won't see apache 404 error page from my knowledge that friendlyness I need to provide..

Comment: @Vishal Yeah, of course. Try to access this page. http://stackoverflow.com/bla I need this kinda response.

Comment: Yes but in that case your URL will be http://localhost:2/sam1/tla not http://localhost:2/sam1222/bla because here sam1 is your application and bla is page

Comment: as you stated in question you already did it.. http://localhost:2/sam1 will be you fixed application URL smiler to stackoverflow.com. stackoverflow123.com this error cannot be handled :)

Comment: @MainshPrajapati so what is your suggestion?

Comment: @Vishal stackoverflow123.com is different in host itself.

Comment: Dear @Pasupathi same way you are trying with you application as well..

Comment: are you able to get any page on http://localhost:2/  ? no right you will not get.. http://localhost:2/sam1/ is full URL this will be fix if any changes in it means different host itself

Comment: @Vishal, There should be someway around tomcat itself. Maybe I'll find it and post the answer. We have option in Tomcat web.xml but it is not working.

Comment: @Vishal for  localhost:2 I have a redirect html in root directory that will redirect to the localhost:2/sam1/home

Comment: @Pasupathi sure please post.. It will be very helpful for all of us.. Best Luck budy..!!

Comment: @Pasupath I  have posted my answer pls check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer after a long struggle.

This can be done only in stand alone Tomcat

We should have the error page in my case `notfound.jsp` in the webapps->Root directory and need to configure the #CATALINA_HOME\conf\web.xml need to add the following

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/notfound.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

And it is successfully getting responded for any URL where it held up with 404

Comment: Good to see that you got solution what you wanted.. :) thanks for posting answer

Answer (score 0):

Please modify 404.jsp under tomcat\webapps\manager\WEB-INF\jsp\ with your custom message. Or Update web.xml of tomcat with

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
     <location>/locationOfErrorPage</location> 
</error-page>
```

Comment: I used to delete everything from tomcat webapp directory other than my sam1 and root. I side root I will only have a htm which will redirect to sam1 app..